# Can we have additional padding on nested lists?

Tags: feature-request, design, markdown-rendering

The padding in nested lists when using blank lines for spacing has always driven me crazy.

I understand that this is because the contents of the list item are simply wrapped in `<p>` and that's why it has to look like this:

1. One

   1. Nest
2. Two

   1. Nester
3. Three

   1. Nestest

Even though the Markdown looks like:

```
1. One
    1. Nest

2. Two
    1. Nester

3. Three
    1. Nestest
```

Tell me what you want, that does not look like what I had in mind. One can try "fixing" it by jamming a couple `&nbsp;` in there, but I would much rather prefer something like this:

```
li > p + ol,
li > p + ul {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

Which renders the above list like:

[image]

From what I can tell, this is something specific to nested lists, so I did not play with any other styles.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think we really need that phantom blank line between `One` and `Nest`, unless the user adds it themselves.

Comment: Personally I'd cut the padding in half and divide it between <del>the poor</del> the top and bottom of the nested items. It's getting a bit too spacy by the revamped one.

Comment: @BenBrocka: Wouldn't mind that either. I just faintly remember posting about this behavior in the past and it was not received well (status-bydesign). So, this time, I wanted to at least propose *some* fix.